# Facebook Canvas APP (Iframed) Auto-Height Resize

Tags: facebook

Been running into an issue lately with Facebook canvas iframe applications. I've set our settings to "auto-resize" and implemented the correct FB JS call to do the resizing of the height (to avoid unwanted scrollbars), but it doesn't seem to be working.

Has anyone else had this issue or come up with a solution?

Thanks!

Erik

Comment: Barbolo's answer at the bottom is the one you are looking for, auto resize has been depreciated and replaced with auto grow, that fixed the same problem for me.

Answer (score 15):

Before `</body>` tag, I have written following code.

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '<?php echo YOUR_APP_ID ?>',
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true,
                    oauth: true
                });
                FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true);
            };
            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol +
                    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
</script>
```

And it is working fine for me.

It doesn't matter whether `height` is `Fixed or Fluid` in Advanced application settings.

`FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true);` was not working in my application, but I found that I missed the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` code. I just put it before `<script type="text/javascript">` and got the issue resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on a couple of points noted already:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ 
           appId: 'YOUR APP ID', 
           status: true, 
           cookie: true, 
           xfbml: true, 
           oauth: true 
        });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true);
    };
```

This will allow dynamic changes in the applications height. Also setting an explicit width in your css like so can help as well:

```css
html {
   width: 760px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: your suggestion help me out a lot with Firefox issue, tx

Comment: the overflow:hidden helped my minor issue that wasn't being fixed by setAutoGrow()

Answer (score 2):

Roozbeh is on the right path with his answer.  However, his code will most likely produce an error (at least in Firefox), as both the old and new SDKs are being referenced (and they don't play well with each other).

Also, just using the new SDK to adjust the height is super simple:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'YOUR APP ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 890 });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>
```

Official documentation available [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.canvas.setsize/).

Comment: Sorry, can't see the difference there... how is this the new one and the one above the old?

Answer (score 2):

FB.Canvas.setAutoResize will be deprecated and you should use FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow as it does exactly what you want.

Comment: sorry to interrupt but i don't get it to work in Firefox?? Both Chrome and IE will autoGrow the canvas. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should ensure that you call this function after document load. It isn't enough to call it after the Facebook script initialization.

Comment: @barbolo Is not right. This function set time interval, therefore, it doesn't really make any difference when you call it the first time. However, this function *is* glitchy and fails quite often, especially in FF9.

Comment: @Guy It actually makes difference. If you call the function after the iframe initialization, it works.

Comment: @barbolo Well, then congratulations on discovering a bug. : )

Answer (score 0):

Auto-resize doesn't work. It's a major bug that facebook has not fixed yet.

However, here's the code work around for the problem:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'YOUR APP ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>
<div id='FB_HiddenContainer' style='display:none;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;width:0;height:0'>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
    FB_RequireFeatures(['CanvasUtil'], function(){
      FB.CanvasClient.setCanvasHeight('1500px');
    });
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ... auto-resize is buggy and only sometimes work

you can set it manually like this:
FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: $('body').height() });

Comment: if jQuery is used inside your application :-)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this problem, its because your `FB.init()` is never being called. In my case, I had it inside my jQuery `document.ready` function. **dont** do that!

Put this outside of your jQuery:

```js
$(function() { ... jquery here... });

// do FB stuff
FB.init({appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true });
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
```