# FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() not working and creating an infinite loop of height changes

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can't get FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() to work.  Or, possibly, its working, and its not doing what I'm expecting?

I've tried setting my Facebook app canvas height fixed and turning off fixed canvas height per the Facebook docs on .setAutoGrow().  I've looking at a number of posts and solutions to this problem including **trying all the solutions from this thread** [Facebook Canvas APP (Iframed) Auto-Height Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982789/facebook-canvas-app-iframed-auto-height-resize).  I've also tried the solution at the Facebook blog: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/. I'm currently trying this websites suggestion http://atomiku.com/2012/02/remove-scrollbars-and-get-your-facebook-app-canvas-iframe-to-autosize-to-height-fb-canvas-setautogrow/#comment-31741 which seems to make more "theoretically correct" sense in my mind,sing onload() --- I would think ONLY happens once.

What I have:
My Facebook application is basically just redirecting to an asp.net page with a master page and that page is nothing special (normal website) except that it is dynamically created and thus the height of each page changes from page to page.  It works fine without fb.canvas.setautogrow(), but has scrollbars on every page on height.  This makes it appear its in a frame.  However, if I use {overflow:hidden;} to remove the scroll bars then the page is truncated.  The scroll bars are removed and if the page is small it looks fine.  As soon as you get to a page that is longer than say the default of 800px, it truncates it.  The style of my body is set to height: 100%;.

My code:
This is my code that is causing infinite readjustments of the height in Facebook.  You literally can scroll to the bottom of Facebook, and the page is getting longer and longer and longer in an infinite loop.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
         FB.init({
             appId: '1234', //Your facebook APP here
             cookie: true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         });
     }

     window.onload = function () {
         FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(91);
     }
    </script>
```

I'm sorry in advance if this is an "obvious" question or the answer is out there and I can't find it.  I have been searching for two days at this point.

Thanks in advance as well for your help.

{Edit:  Ok, this problem appears to be ONLY happening in IE.  I didn't realize that at first.  I'm using IE 11.}

Comment: Do you mean that your problem is that the page is continually increasing in size as you scroll to the bottom? I'm guessing that's not your intent; you simply want the page to be as high as the content?

Comment: Yeh, I'm looking the iframe to be the "same" size as the content with no scroll bars so it looks like its part of Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '1234', //Your facebook APP here
        cookie: true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
```

You need to call FB functions AFTER you initialize the JavaScript SDK. You also need no parameter for `setAutoGrow`, i think the default is 100ms (so it checks every 100ms for height changes).

Also, always use the asynchronous version, exactly like it is explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0

I don´t think this will fix your loop problem though. If your content gets larger the whole time, there´s probably a CSS problem. height set to 100% maybe? I had that problem once.

Another problem could be the redirection, remove the redirection and try using it (with the correct code) on the URL you set in the Page Tab settings.

Edit: So my guess with 100% height did solve the first problem, now you can check if content is placed with `position:absolute`. Facebook does not increase the height if you are only using content with absolute position.

Comment: Nope--tried it.  Like I said in my post, I already tried that code initially.  That's the code already documented as answered to the problem in the stackflow post. That solution Doesn't WORK for me.  CSS for html body is already set to 100% height...and it really doesn't matter whether the 100% is there or not, it still does it.  The parameter is simply a result of the alternative solution I posted from that other page that uses onload().  It really doesn't matter, the behavior is the same in both situations.

Comment: so, can we have a link for testing? else it´s going to be hard to help. and please do not set height to 100% for testing, just in case :)

Comment: in any case, your code is completely wrong btw. you are using the synchronous way to load the sdk (that´s bad already) and you are using the async callback (fbAsyncInit). again, ALWAYS use the code from the facebook docs. it may not solve your problem right now, but you may have a lot more problems later if you don´t use the correct code.

Comment: Ok, rereading your post.  You are saying the height set to 100% could be the problem!!  I was thinking you were saying I need to set the height to 100%. I removed all instances of Height: 100% in my style sheet....actually did a search through the whole project and removed them.  I even changed the code to what you suggest as that is what I had originally anyways.  It did in fact STOP the infinite reload!

However, now I'm back to the default behavior as if there was no code there at all.  Facebook puts scrolling in and if I HIDE the scrolling, then the page is truncated in the iframe.

Comment: Again, a test link would help a LOT. Anyway, do you add content with position:absolute?

Comment: Sure.   I have to make the app public.  Go here --> https://www.facebook.com/pages/SalesCart/262298343784373?ref_type=bookmark  and click on the SHOP app.  Oh, and <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script> doesn't do anything.  It is what I use to resize the .js outside of Facebook and actually solves this problem like a charm in that environment.  No I'm not using position:Absolute

Comment: do you mean the SalesCart app? because there is no "shop" app, maybe it´s restricted or not public yet. and there is no javascript sdk on the salescart app as far as i can see.

Comment: Well I just made it public...I'm not sure if there is some kind of delay.  Can you try and go directly here-->  https://www.facebook.com/pages/SalesCart/262298343784373?sk=app_453183128105357  Thanks

Comment: that is the app i went to. i cannot find any javascript sdk in the source, and it says "Sorry, you must be logged in as a Facebook user to view this app!".

Comment: Yeh, it needs you to be logged into Facebook as a user.  If you go into Facebook and log in first and then click on the link, it should work.  Once it redirects, then you will see the problem.  This first set of code you are seeing is not really relevant.

Comment: i did click on the link, it redirects to a canvas page and says "You must login as a user not as a page!" - but i AM logged in as a user.

Comment: ah well, this taking longer than expected, this is usually a very easy problem to fix. just change your css and test with an easier page with less content. if it increases the height the whole time with a lot of whitespace, it means that setAutoGrow works perfectly fine and the problem is with css.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bug...Its fixed now!  The app really wasn't 100% ready yet...I just opened it up for you to see it.  It will let you see the page now and you can see the .js code and the css content.  Its pretty basic css.  I'm not sure exactly what the problem would be with css.  I'm not even getting consistent behavior on the infinite height.  It seems to happen when I log in with one Facebook account but when I use a different one, it doesn't happen.  It doesn't work in either case though.  (Sorry, its taking so long)

Comment: now it looks completely different. and it seems that setAutoGrow works as expected. when i click on "what´s new", the content gets a tiny bit higher. the js code is still not correct though, you should really use the async way to load the javascript sdk. especially if you use the fbAsyncInit function anyway. weird to use the synchronous way to load it, but the async way to check if it´s loaded...

Comment: Click on Departments>>merchant services>>equipment>>Veriphone.  It not really changing the iframe size.  Its simply giving you a SCROLL.  If I turn the scroll off, you will see the iframe height is fixed.  You want me turn it off so you can see what I'm talking about?  The code you linked to from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0 is on that page as well?

Comment: Don't you also see a huge amount of extra white space at what looks like the bottom of the page from the constant  setautogrows()?

Comment: well, i clicked on the department link now, there is an error: Server Error in '/store20' Application.

Comment: Like I said, not really ready for primetime.  It appears to be some kind of memory leak...so with multiple people going to it, its crashing.  However, I turned the scroll off and its definitely NOT showing me the bottom of the page.  It should have the word CONTACT with a black background at the bottom of EVERY page if its working.  Everytime, I look at it, I see something different currently so I'm not sure anymore what it is doing.  I'll reboot it but going to have to shut it down here shortly and find where the memory leak is.

Comment: I'm looking at it with IE though....  It looks ok in Google CHROME.  So maybe this is an IE problem of some kind???  Thanks for your help...I'm starting to think this problem is unique to IE.

Comment: Now, with IE, I see someone else has had this problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962374/facebook-canvas-setautogrow-grows-forever-in-ie

Comment: yeah, i see it now. some hints: always use the html5 doctype, i get a message in the console about the compatibility mode. i also get a syntax error in the console.

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed the html5 doctype.  Going to eat some lunch now...my brain is hurting.  I "THINK" I might have fixed the memory leak...at least I found an obvious problem.